# Error while trying to save an image into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created code to upload an image into SQL Server.

Here is the code to convert the image into bytes:

```
//Use FileInfo object to get file size.
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(p);         

//Open FileStream to read file
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] numBytes = new byte[fStream.Length];
fStream.Read(numBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fStream.Length));

//Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.

//BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

//When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file.
//In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.

// data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
return numBytes;
```

And here is the  code to add the bytes to a `SqlCommand` parameter as values:

```
 objCmd.Parameters.Add("@bill_Image", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = imageData;
  objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I am getting error

> *String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated*

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: What's the column size in SQL Server? The error is basically telling you that you are trying to store more bytes than allowed in the column.

Comment: If your column length is `max` already then check if there are any triggers on the table?

Comment: I have change the column to Max and I am not using triggers in the table

Answer (score 4):

Error is clearly indicating that you're trying to save more bytes than allowed by the field definition.

Not sure what sql type you're using for `bill_Image` but an appropiated field definition to store an image would be `varbinary(MAX)`.

Comment: hi i have changed the code like      objCmd.Parameters.Add("@bill_Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary,-1).Value = imageData;    and still getting the same error.

Comment: and also i worked with objCmd.Parameters.Add("@bill_Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imageData; but still got the same error

Comment: @jeevacl: could you post you sql field definition for `bill_Image`?

Comment: "bill_Image varbinary(MAX) Checked"  this is the field definition in the table

Comment: @jeevacl - So are there any insert triggers on the table? If so what are the definitions of those? not please add the SQL you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Check definition of the `bill_Image` column in your database.

it should be something like

```
bill_Image varbinary(X)
```

Just increase X or put there MAX instead of a number (if you have more than 8 000 bytes image)

Info about binary/varbinary type [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)

Comment: made the changes everything as your suggestion and still getting the same error...\

Comment: @jeevacl do you have any other fields set with that request? This error simply indicates that length of some field is smaller than length of data you are trying to put in. Also, what is the size of your image?

Comment: image size is 858kb. it is the windows sample image

Comment: Check other fields. binary/varbinary(max) should allow you to put up to 2gb in one field